# How to calculate number of contributors to a JIRA release?

Tags: jira, release

We have a fixVersion field we denote that contains a "release id".

We would like to understand, historically, the number of people who contributes to the "X" number of JIRA issues that contain a specific release id.

To define contributors, this may end up simply being the "assignee" of the Issue, but could also include authors of associated code reviews.

Does anyone have advice on how to build this type of reporting in JIRA?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of contributors to a JIRA release:

1. Access the release in JIRA.
2. Look for a release report or commit history.
3. Use JQL to filter issues for the release.
4. Explore activity streams for contributor updates.
5. Consider third-party plugins for detailed reporting.

Comment: This is a very manual way of determining contributors. In our case, we have dozens of releases, and each release contains dozens of Epics/Stories/Issues. Hoping there is a report that can be utilized to expedite this.